# How to get NO context when using svn diff

Tags: svn, command-line, diff

When I use 'svn diff' from the command line, it prints out the lines that have changed but also the 3 unchanged lines before and after for context. I much prefer seeing only the changed lines with no context. I haven't been able to determine any command line options that will let me make it behave this way. Standard 'diff' and 'cvs diff' do what I want by default. Surely 'svn diff' can do this but I'm missing something. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After looking into the useful link given above by unwind, the short answer is that svn's built-in diff can't do what I want. You can tell it to use the standard external diff though and pass arg's to that to tell it that you want no context. I put the following alias in my .bashrc and all now works well if I use that instead:

```
alias svndiff='svn diff --diff-cmd=diff -x -U0'
```

Comment: `-x` is the extension parameter for `svn diff`, it causes the token immediately following, here `-U0`, to be passed to the diff command specified with `--diff-cmd`, here `diff`.

Answer (score 7):

The suggestion above still produces the context format, but with 0 lines of context. This is still not the traditional diff output from before subversion.

What works for me is: `svn di --diff-cmd=diff -x --normal`

The `--normal` option (in the diff that ships with OSX) gives the traditional format that some folks prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You could pipe the results of 'svn diff' to grep and write a regular expression to get what you want. For example, try this:

```
svn diff | grep "^[+-\]"
```

The above command gets you all lines that begin with a '+' or a '-' or a '\'. (You need the '\' if you want to see differences such as "\ No newline at the end of the file".)

Comment: This works fine if you want only the changed lines. However, it fails to output correct information about line numbers. E.g. with 3 lines of context before/after, "@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@" says line 24 was changed. With no context you'd see "@@ -24,1 +24,1 @@"

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2003-12/0668.shtml) seems to come to the conclusion that you should use an external diff command in order to control the amount of context.

I prefer unified diffs, so my fingers always type

```
svn diff -x -u
```

Which implies that an external (GNU diff) command is used, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. Surprising to me that the built-in diff can't do what I want. Seems to me to violate the Unix principle of having the least output asked for.

Using the -x -u commands gives me the same results as not. 'svn help diff' tell me that those are the defaults. Maybe you don't need to type the extra char's after all?