# SVN Summary of Changes for Release (Count of Lines Added, Deleted, and Modified by File)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, project-management, release, release-management

I've read several posts and did lots of googling today but haven't found what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to find a built in way to be able to tell the number of lines added, deleted and modified (by file) for a release (between two changeset numbers of a branch)

If I run:
`svn diff -r3038:HEAD`

I can see the differences from the revision 3038 to the head with the details of the differences. When I add `--summarize` I get the list of all files as add, edit or delete, but I don't get the details of how large of changes each is.

`svn diff -r3038:HEAD --summarize`

I've read several others posts, such as [How to get NO context when using svn diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577921/how-to-get-no-context-when-using-svn-diff)

I'm running svn on a CentOS server but connecting to it via tortoise svn on a windows 8 machine. I found the statistics of the tortoise svn's show log interface to be limited to only the number of checkings and of very limited ability. I assume with SVN's popularity that there would be something built in, but I haven't found anything clean, easy and built in.

I found (https://github.com/marschall/svn-diffstat) but am trying to find something built in that can provide the information, I don't need pretty charts, just the summary of lines for adds, deletes, and modifies. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Continuing to play with things, I found a possible answer, which I'm posting as a baseline answers.

I'll see if anyone has any better approaches.

I found out that the server has `diffstat` on it (http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/), which lets me get the info I need.

`svn diff -r3038:HEAD http://10.100.10.2/svn/repos/Path/To/Branch | diffstat > branchstats.txt`